# Knockout MVC with existing C# code - looping

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

The code in my view -

```
@{ int tabIndex = 0; }
        @using (var metricGroup = ko.Foreach(m => m.MetricGroups))
        {
            tabIndex++;
            <div id="tabs-@tabIndex" > ... </div>
         }
```

The issue here is for all the divs rendered, the id is always the same - "tabs-1"
instead of that, it should be "tabs-1", "tabs-2", "tabs-3" ...

Can anyone please help me out with this issue?
I have a highly complex view and Knockout MVC is driving me crazy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the `ko.Foreach` your HTML will be generated on the **client side**, so setting the  your div's id with Razor does not work because the Razor code is executed on server side.

What you need to do is to generate the id's on the client side with Knockout using the `$index()` [binding context property](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html), and the [`attr` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html):

```
@using (var metricGroup = ko.Foreach(m => m.MetricGroups))
{
    <div data-bind="attr: { id: 'tabs-' + $index() }" > ... </div>
}
```

The Knockout-Mvc's `ko.Bind.Attr` method is not working with the `GetIndex()` method so you need to write out the this Knockout binding expression by hand.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this earlier but i am facing one issue. This code generates the Ids but since we are using index, they look like id=0, id=1, id=2 .... I tried using  <div data-bind="attr: { id: 'tabs-' + $index() + 1 }" > ... </div> But that didnt work either. What i want is ids should start from 1,2,3...

Comment: You just need to correctly group the expression: `<div data-bind="attr: { id: 'tabs-' + ( $index() + 1 ) }" >` note the `( )` http://jsfiddle.net/S8KQP/